# $ and % symbols in POSIX(unix) console

Tags: bash, macos, unix, posix, cat

[It's my bash script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgBak.png)

[When I run my script and cat -e output from this script.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmHby.png)

What is mean % and $ characters?

Comment: Please put the relevant parts in your question (and in text), not in links and/or pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cat -e` will print 'unprintable characters' such as new line indicators

`$` in this instance indicates the presence of a `\n` character which is an `EOL` (end of line).

The `%` character appears in certain shell environments when you have exited a stream without the presence of a newline character on the end (the effect of your `tr -d '\n'`). It isn't technically part of the output, rather an indicator inserted after the output has been rendered to the terminal.

ie, you can strip the `$` from the displayed output by piping it back through tr:

`$ echo "hello\nhello" | cat -e | tr -d '$'
hello
hello`

but you can't strip the % from the displayed output by doing the same thing:

`$ echo "hello\nhello" | tr -d '\n' | cat -e | tr -d '%'
hellohello%`

Comment: where can I find docs about this?

Comment: well I would start with the manual for `cat`

Comment: The % is a function of the shell, I would suspect the OP is using zsh. There are options to change this value which can be found at http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Prompting

Answer (score 0):

The `$` and `%` are default prompt symbols used by convention.  They appear at the end of the prompt.  Your output does not have a newline at the end, so the prompt appears on the end of the line.

`$` indicates a shell derived from the Bourne-shell, which includes POSIX, Korn, and Bash shells.  These shells use a `#` when signed on with a user ID of zero (usually root).

The `%` indicates a shell derived from the c-shell, which includes csh and tcsh.

So you are *probably* running under the c-shell, and then you are running a POSIX or Bourne-shell script (your `#!` line shows `sh`), so the `bash` tag is misleading.  *Probably* because you can set the prompt, variable `PS1`, to be anything you like, overriding the conventions described above.

To see which shell you are running, just type `ps | grep $$`

I don't see any `$` signs in the output you show, exerpt from `man cat`:

*-e      Display non-printing characters (see the -v option), and display a dollar sign (`$') at the end of each line.*